# Achar o maior valor em vetor

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Um programa que pede para achar o maior número de um vetor, digitando a quantidade de elementos e até que elemento ele vai verificar. Porém, neste programa que fiz ele não está considerando o primeiro elemento digitado. Se eu digito 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ele diz que o maior é o 4. Não tenho ideias de como resolver

```
int i, qntd, n;
printf ("Digite a quantidade de elementos: ");
scanf ("%d", &qntd);
printf ("Ate onde considerar: ");
scanf ("%d", &n);

float vet[qntd], maior = 0;

for (i = 0; i < qntd; i++) {        //Preencher o vetor
    printf ("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf ("%f", &vet[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        vet[i] = maior;
    }
    if (vet[i] > maior) {
        maior = vet[i];
    }
}
printf ("Maior = %.2f \n", maior);



system ("PAUSE");
```

Comment: Certeza que precisa ler um número para quantidade e outro para o `n`? Aproveitando, sua entrada está incompleta: você não disse qual `qntd` e qual `n` você digitou. E se disse sua entrada está com 2 números a menos do que deveria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você se confundiu na primeira linha que atribuiu o valor a maior.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        vet[i] = maior;
    }
    if (vet[i] > maior) {
        maior = vet[i];
    }
}
```

O certo seria:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        maior = vet[i];
    }
    if (vet[i] > maior) {
        maior = vet[i];
    }
}
```

Como os dois if's são iguais, você nem precisaria dessa verificação.

Claro, neste caso não funcionaria para números negativos, dado que você inicializa a variável "maior" com zero. Você poderia fazer essa atribuição então imediatamente antes do for:

```
maior = vet[0];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (vet[i] > maior)
           maior = vet[i];
    }
}
```

São muitas formas de resolver seu problema, mas o único engano foi na primeira atribuição.

Comment: Poxa, muito obrigado. Algo tão simples que não consegui pensar na hora

Answer (score 1):

Tem erros aí, mas o código é complexo demais, pode ser muito mais simples que isto. E o enunciado não é bom, para que serve pedir até onde deve verificar? Se não vai verificar o resto nem pede os outros dados, mas vou manter o algoritmo fazendo algo sem sentido mesmo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
    int qntd, n;
    printf ("Digite a quantidade de elementos: ");
    scanf ("%d", &qntd);
    printf ("Ate onde considerar: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    float vet[qntd], maior = FLT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < qntd; i++) {
        printf ("Digite um numero: ");
        scanf ("%f", &vet[i]);
        if (i < n && vet[i] > maior) maior = vet[i];
    }
    printf ("Maior = %.2f \n", maior);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FlBj75). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Maxc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Max.c).

Você tem que que pegar o menor `float`possível, 0 não é o menor, nada impede de ser digitado um valor negativo, a não ser que tivesse que fazer essa validação de acordo com o enunciado, mas não faz isto. E você pode filtrar e achar o maior logo quando entra os dados não precisa fazer outro laço para isto. Pra falar a verdade nem deveria criar um vetor, eu só não quis mudar demais o código, mas uma variável simples resolve, o enunciado não pede para armazenar no vetor.

Boa parte dos erros deste tipo ocorrer quando começa complicar de mais o código. O melhor código é aquele que não existe,m por isso procure fazer da forma mais simples. Note que o erro desapareceu só simplificando.